# Yii2. Получить параметры в beforesave

Tags: php, yii2

Хочу перед тем, как сохранить строку в базе, сделать некие манипуляции.  Но данных находящихся в `$this` не хватает

```
 public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

        //Здесь некоторое действие, допустим с переменной $age

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Скажите, как правильно передать параметр в beforeSave, который не относится к модели?

Comment: что значит `данных находящихся в $this не хватает`? ......можешь внутри `beforeSave` вызвать метод какого-нибудь другого нужно тебе класса

Comment: Допустим в контроллере у меня есть переменная $age, я вызываю метод $model-save(). Как мне ее передать в beforesave, чтобы я мог выполнить с ней манипуляции там? В данной таблице модели столбца age нет.

Comment: а что это за переменная? Откуда она берется и  для чего? Почему её нет в модели? и как ты собираешься сделать `save` если её нет? что ты вообще с ней хочешь сделать?

Comment: Мне нужно послать ее на внешнюю систему через АПИ. Если АПИ дал отрицательный ответ, то выполнить save модели. Я в контроллере вызываю save модели. Там же до save появляется эта переменная.

Comment: а почему в `beforeSave`? А если сохранение пройдет неудачно? Может тогда в данном случае если `if ($model-save())` то тогда и посылать что-то куда-то? есессно уже через тот модуль/модель, что ответствененна за обмен данными через АПИ

Comment: да, но если я от АПИ не получу нужный ответ? Как отменить сохранение?
Только транзакцией?
А так, если beforesave даст false, то и сохранения не произойдет

Comment: `Мне нужно послать ее на внешнюю систему через АПИ. Если АПИ дал отрицательный ответ, то выполнить save модели` - ни.че.го.не.по.нят.но.... Если `save` зависит от ответа АПИ, которой посылается переменная, то причем тут вообще beforeSave, до которого даже не должно дойти дело в случае правильного ответа от АПИ? Достаточно тогда, как я описал еще в первом комментарии,  передать переменную в любой метод любого класса  и обработать её так, как требуется. Затем отдать её в АПИ и т.д.

Comment: Ок. Давайте рассмотрим ситуацию. В АПИ я записал. Все хорошо. Потом делаю save модели. А там ошибка. В итоге в Апи записал, а в свою базу нет.

Comment: но ты же писал что "Если АПИ дал **отрицательный ответ**, то выполнить save модели". из твоих слов становится понятно, что ты либо в АПИ шлешь, либо в базу) Либо ты путаешься в даче показаний)

Comment: да, ошибся выше. Если даст положительный